# return at least one unique value for low-boost fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine, we have a document {position, primary_language, secondary_language}

Let it contains next data:

```
Junior Software Developer,  python,  ruby
Senior Software Developer,  ruby,    python
Python Software Developer,  python,  php
Ruby Junior Developer,      ruby,    php
Programmer,                 ruby,    python
Python Programmer,          python,  php
.....
...and more and more lines
```

And I do multi_match search for 'python' against position, primary_language, secondary_language with result size=5

What I want:

- I want at least 1 row, where 'python' contains in the position field
- I want at least 1 row, where 'python' contains in the
  primary_language field
- I want at least 1 row, where 'python' contains
  in the secondary_language field

If I play with 'boost', I could get 5 results with python in primary or secondary, but not in position, also with boosting position I could return 5 results with 'python' in position title, but nothing in primary and secondary.

I generally I'm building something like distinct from sql.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Found that dismax filter works for me, thought it's native behavior quite different - checking this paper http://searchhub.org/2010/05/23/whats-a-dismax/

Comment: did you try a boolean query?

Comment: short answer - it doesn't help, I used dis_max query - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html with high tie_breaker values and looks like it gives good results, will check it on more testing